# User Register forms, two types of user roles, with multiple custom fields

Tags: wordpress, roles

Hi i have a difficult  wordpress problem in front of me.
I'm developing the site that has two user roles Teachers and students. They have a **frontend** user registration form that is complex and has multiple custom fields. Teacher form should register user with role of teacher. Student the same, has custom fields and should register users with role student.
Also both user roles can create and edit content and user profiles via frontend form and not try admin. 
What is the best way to do this. And where to start.

Comment: Hi! Your question is a bit too broad for this site as there are likely several correct answers. If you are unsure of where to start, you might want to hire a consultant to help you design a solution.

Comment: Unfortunately i can't afford a consultant. Til now i have found this link http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Registration_Form and it helps with user registration

Comment: Yes - you should try following that guide, and if you run into problems you can post them as questions here. StackOverflow isn't free free consulting work :/

Comment: Thank you, now i'm searching try codex guide for frontend editing custom post types.